# How to get the size of String java.util.Map.Entry.getKey() in java?

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I tried some options but I could not get my required output.

The question is how to get the size of `m.getKey()`

I tried `m.getKey().length` ,`m.getKey().size` but I could not find.

```
System.out.print("\n duplicate words: ");
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> m:  map.entrySet()){
if(m.getValue()>toStringArray.length-1)
);
System.out.print(m.getKey() + " ");
}
```

The output is

> ( HI THIS IS MY OUTPUT)

The output which I needed is

> (5) //HI THIS IS MY OUTPUT total count is 5

Suggestions are Welcomed.

I am a beginner to java

Here is my Full code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;


public class testduplicatewordnew {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

/* Reading text content from file    */
 FileInputStream fisTargetFile = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\testfolder\\மிரளச் செய்யும் மிலரபாவின் கதை!  Isha Tamil Blog 15.txt"));

    String targetFileStr = IOUtils.toString(fisTargetFile, "UTF-8");

 String []toStringArray = targetFileStr.split(" ");


 HashMap<String , Integer> map = analyzeWords("Analyzing contents ", toStringArray);



 System.out.print("\nduplicate words: ");
 for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> m:  map.entrySet()){
 if(m.getValue()>toStringArray.length-1)
// System.out.print(m.getKey() + "-" + m.getValue()/(toStringArray.length-1) + " ");
  System.out.print(m.getKey()+ " ");
 // System.out.println(map.keySet().size());
// System.out.println(m.getValue());


}
 System.out.println("\n");
 }

 private static HashMap<String, Integer> analyzeWords(String command, String []toStringArray ){
System.out.println(command);  

HashMap<String, Integer> unik = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  

int i =0;
while(i<toStringArray.length){ unik.put(toStringArray[i++], 0);}

 for(i = 0; i< toStringArray.length; i++){   
 for(int j = 0; j< toStringArray.length; j++ ){
 if( (toStringArray[i] != toStringArray[j]) && (i != j))
  unik.put(toStringArray[i],(int)unik.get(toStringArray[i]) +1);
 }
 }// oef outter for loop


 return unik;
 }// eof analyzeWords method

 /* method to read file content.
  * returns the contents of text file as a string */
 private static String fileNameReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
System.out.println("\nReading " +fileName+ " file");
String generateString = "";
try{   
 File file = new File(fileName);
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

 generateString = scanner.nextLine();
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      generateString = generateString + "\n" + scanner.nextLine();
 }scanner.close();
 System.out.println("\nInitial content");
 System.out.println(generateString);
}catch(IOException e){
 System.out.println("\nError occured while reading file...");
 }
return generateString;
 }// eof fileNameReader method
}
```

Comment: `m.getKey().length()` ? `m.getValue();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like bellow to count words in key:

```
String keys = "";
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> m:  map.entrySet()){
 if(m.getValue()>toStringArray.length-1)
    keys = keys + " " + m.getKey();
}
System.out.print(keys.trim().split("\\s+").length);
```

Comment: huh nope :/ I got output as 111111.

Comment: I've edited the code. Now this approach may help you. Take a variable named **keys** to append all keys and then split **keys** by using space and print length.

Comment: Yeah exactly what I needed.But the count shows 6 instead of 5 For  (HI THIS IS MY OUTPUT).And for every text file the count is +1 for other output. Why so?

Comment: oh! you need to **trim()** before split. Code edited plz check :)

Comment: And I need to load many text files from a folder path "E:\\testfolder" and apply the code for all of it is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101255/discussion-between-ram-ki-and-muzahidul-islam).

Answer (score 2):

you can get the size using:

```
map.keySet().size()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use m.getValue() directly and m.getKey() returns type is Integer that does not have size.

map.keySet().size()

Comment: If i give m.getValue() the output shows 112 334 556 332 445.

Comment: I almost understand you! Just map.keySet().size() is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Since m.getKey() method returns an object of class Object if the method is not used inside the `println` method, it has to be type-casted to String to access the length() method as follows:

```
((String)e.getKey()).length();
```

Comment: No it doesn't return String but returns Object if it is not used inside println method. See Java docs.

Comment: Huh... No - according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey--) it returns a `K`, which in the example of the question is a String...

Comment: if I give length() it shows 0 8 11 7 8 10 like this

Comment: Yup but the JVM treats that K as Object...Even eclipse shows Object as the return type.

Comment: @RameshSingh you are confused... It may be treated as an object at runtime - but the compiler knows it's a String so you don't need a cast. That's the whole point of generics.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();`

to get the number of keys, use `((String[]) map.keySet()).size()`

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for amount of words in map keys, you can get the output by `map.size()` Map keys have to be unique and if you looking for duplicates in key set you shouldn't get them because they don't exist.